# An EventListener is not removed and added again, is this problematic?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

when the user clicks 'on' an EventListener gets added:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', getCursorXY, false);
```

when the user clicks 'off' the EventListener is not removed and when the user clicks 'on' again the same EventListener gets added again:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', getCursorXY, false);
```

Is this problematic? Are there two Listeners running then, or is the first just overwritten with the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using `addEventListener` over properties like `onclick` is that you can attach as many event handlers as you'd like to on the element.

This also means that adding another event handler does **not** automatically remove the previously set event handlers, as that would defeat the purpose, you have to remove those manually with [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener).

```
document.removeEventListener('mousemove', getCursorXY, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have multiple event listeners firing for that event. Even if the code somehow manages to work correctly, it's inefficient, and something you should take care to avoid.

The `mousemove` event is fired by the browser very often, and it's really important to code any event handlers efficiently for this event, and to make sure you don't end up with a ton of listeners for it. Sometimes you need multiple listeners, and by all means do it if you need it, but you don't need it from what I'm seeing.

I recommend you just keep track of the fact that you already added the listener, and use that fact to avoid adding the listener twice.